# angularjs data is not showing in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, asmx

I am creating a web app in which I am using angularjs for SQL connectivity.

I have two users (`admin`,`Regional Partner Manager`) data of admin is showing properly on my table but data of Regional Partner manager Is Not showing.

Here is my js file:

```
$scope.getsonvindata = function () {
            $scope.loadimage = true;
            $scope.names = '';
            $scope.resetfilters();
            //$scope.area = location;
            // get sonvin data list and stored in sonvinrpm $scope variable 
            $http.get('/angularwebservice/frmcosonvinrpm4.asmx/frmsonvinrpm', {
                params: {
                    log: log,
                    from: $scope.from,
                    to: $scope.to,
                    pm: pm
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.sonvinrpm = response.data.procompanysonVin;
                console.log($scope.sonvinrpm);
                //pagination
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.sonvinrpm.length;
                $scope.numPerPage = 50000;
                $scope.paginate = function (value) {
                    var begin, end, index;
                    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
                    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                    index = $scope.sonvinrpm.indexOf(value);
                    return (begin <= index && index < end);
                };

                $scope.loadimage = false;
                if ($scope.sonvinrpm == '') {
                    $scope.errormessage = 'Data Not Found... Please Select Correct Date Range';
                }
                else {
                    $scope.errormessage = '';
                }
            });
```

My table:

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width: 110%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary">
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('name')" class="erp-tb-a">SrNo</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('date')" class="erp-tb-a">Date</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('venuename')" class="erp-tb-a">Hotel/School</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('venue')" class="erp-tb-a">Venue</a></th>                                 
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('zone')" class="erp-tb-a">Zone</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('location')" class="erp-tb-a">Location</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('starttime')" class="erp-tb-a">Start Time</a></th>             
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('brand')" class="erp-tb-a">Brand Name</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#" ng-click="order('program')" class="erp-tb-a">Program</a></th>

                            <%--<th>Count</th>--%>                         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <%--<th>SonvinId</th>--%>
                        <td>
                            <div class="left-margin form-control-wrapper form-group has-feedback has-feedback">
                                <input type="text" class="date floating-label erp-input" ng-model="search.date" placeholder="Date">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search.venuename" placeholder="Hotel/School" class="erp-input" /></td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="text" ng-model="search.venue" placeholder="Venue" class="erp-input" />
                        </td>
                        <%--<th>Day</th>--%>
                        <%--<th>Company</th>--%>
                       <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search.zone" placeholder="Zone" class="erp-input" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search.location" placeholder="Location" class="erp-input"></td>
                        <td>
                            <%--<div class="form-control-wrapper"> id="time"--%>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="search.starttime" class="floating-label erp-input" placeholder="Start Time">
                            <%--</div>--%>
                        </td>
                        <%-- <th>End</th>--%>
                        <%--<th>Hrs</th>--%>
                         <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search.brand" placeholder="Brand Name" class="erp-input" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search.program" placeholder="Program" class="erp-input" /></td>                          
                    </tr>
                    <%--| filter :{date: mddate,brand: mdbrand, zone: mdzone, location: mdlocation, starttime: mdstart,program: mdprogram,venuename: mdvenuename,venue: mdvenue }--%>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in sonvinrpm | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate| filter:search">
                        <td><button type="button" ng-click="getassigntrainerdata(x)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assigntrainermodel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></td>
                        <td>{{x.srno}}</td>
                        <%--<td>{{x.sonvinid}}</td>--%>
                        <td>{{x.date}}</td>

                        <td class="bg-success"><a ng-bind="x.venuename" ng-click="DetailsFunction(x)" class="erp-table-a" data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detailsmodel"></a></td>
                        <td>{{x.venue}}</td>
                        <%-- <td>{{x.day}}</td>--%>
                        <%--<td>{{x.company}}</td>--%>                         
                        <td>{{x.zone}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.location}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.starttime}}</td>
                        <%--<td>{{x.endtime}}</td>--%>
                        <%--<td>{{x.hrs}}</td>--%>
                        <td>{{x.brand}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.program}}</td>
                       <%--<td>count</td>--%>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="12"><pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm"></pagination></td>
                    </tr>  
                        </tbody>                                     
                </table>
```

and now the data I am getting from web service for my Regional Partner Manager:

```
{"procompanysonVin":[{"srno":1,"sonvinid":null,"id":3401,"date":"22-10-2016","day":"Sat       ","company":24,"brand":"QED - TM","zone":"East","location":"Kolkata ","starttime":"10:00","endtime":"12:00","hrs":"02:00:00  ","program":"HBKBH","venuename":" NARAYANA SCHOOL","venue":" SITLA ASANSOL"},{"srno":2,"sonvinid":null,"id":3400,"date":"23-10-2016","day":"Sun       ","company":24,"brand":"QED - TM","zone":"East","location":"Kolkata ","starttime":"10:00","endtime":"12:00","hrs":"02:00:00  ","program":"HBKBH","venuename":"NARAYANA SCHOOL","venue":" BENGAL AMBUJA HOUSING COMPLEX AMBUJA DURGAPUR WEST BENGAL"}]}
```

the data is coming in my webservice, what is wrong here?

NOTE: data of admin is printing on my table but not of regional partner manager

Comment: have you tried loading your data before displaying the table? ng-if="sonvinrpm && search" at the beginning of your table
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width: 110%;" ng-if="sonvinrpm && search">

Comment: i think problem on  $scope.sonvinrpm in  http get response , can you print  what data come  console.log($scope.sonvinrpm); ithink it should be "                $scope.sonvinrpm = response.procompanysonVin;" remove data from this 
according to your response

Comment: The issue may be with  `filter:search` once remove it and check if it is coming, later we can add it. 
`<tr ng-repeat="x in sonvinrpm | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is i was not able to find where are you calling $scope.getsonvindata function. You are just defining function but not calling anywhere in the code. like this

```
$scope.getsonvindata();
```

Second is you have applied filters wrongly.
Here is the proper way to set order by filter.
add scope

```
$scope.predicate = 'venue';
$scope.reverse = true;
```

then add to the ng-repeat
    orderBy:predicate:reverse

Here is the working link
https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27907/

Answer (score 0):

In the `.then(function ()` You have set

```
$scope.sonvinrpm = response.data.procompanysonVin;
```

But while setting data in the table you have set data model as `search.zone`, `search.location`, `search.date` etc.

Firstly you need to correct the key for data access.

Secondly the data which you are getting from the http request is an object which contains array.

So you need to use `ng-repeat` (or any other iterating logic) to traverse the data for displaying in the table.

Thirdly, `sonvinrpm` is an object, So you need to do `null` or `undefined` check

```
if ($scope.sonvinrpm == '') {
    $scope.errormessage = 'Data Not Found... Please Select Correct Date Range';
}
```

should be replaced with

```
if (!$scope.sonvinrpm) {
    $scope.errormessage = 'Data Not Found... Please Select Correct Date Range';
}
```